# LINQ query testing against a database

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq

im just starting to learn LINQ and at the same time im working on a research project for school on using link to entities with oracle and DB2   im trying to find a tool or addon that i can use to test my result sets so that i can run a linq query and see the resulting data i have seen LINQ pad but it seems to be set up for microsoft sql server  and compact is there a similar tool that i can use to test against alternate databases out there or a way to setup linq pad to be used with foreign databases

Comment: ever hear of a period or punctuation? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are just looking for a tool to see linq queries get executed, and their results?

If you want to take the "profiling" approach Entity Framework Profiler (http://efprof.com/) would do the trick.  It allows you to see linq statements get executed, time spent querying, sql generated,  as well as see the result set that is returned.  Its not a test tool by any means... its free for 30 days and after that you will need to pay for a license.

I think you would be better off by using MS Unit Test framework and just validating the results programmatically.

Comment: thanks the profiler sounds like a good option i also found that linqpad and linqer are excellent tools as well